# navigate function in Gatsy return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Faced a problem with the `navigate()` in Gatsy function, using the navigate function, you can pass an object as a second parameter to another page. I did as in the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#how-to-use-the-navigate-helper-function), but when getting data I get undefined.

```
const Panel = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  useEffect (() => {
    if (name !== undefined) {
      setName('Hello World')
    }
  }, [name])

  const handleRedirect = () => {
    navigate('/cabinet/', { state: { name }})
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleRedirect}>Redirect</button>
      <div>
  )
}

const Cabinet = ({location}) => {

  console.log(location.state.name) // undefined

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{location.state.name}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a matter of timings/asynchronously. Your `navigate` built-in function looks good, however, you are setting the `name` (with your `setName` setter) after the navigation occurs. In addition, you are missing the `key` for the state. Try something like:

```
  const handleRedirect = () => {     
    if(name) navigate('/cabinet', {state: {'name': name}}); // Try hardcoding Hello World for debugging purposes {'name'; 'Hello World'}
  }
```

Then in your Cabinet component:

```
const Cabinet = ({location}) => {

  console.log(location.state.name) // will be your Hello World

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{location.state.name}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Alternatively, you can do an `async`/`await` approach, something like:

```
  const setNameFunction = ()=>{
      setName('Hello World')
    
      return name 
   }

  const handleRedirect = async () => {
    let  nameFromFunction= await setNameFunction;

    navigate('/cabinet/', { state: { 'name': nameFromFunction }}) // use if(nameFromFunction) navigate('/cabinet/', { state: { name: nameFromFunction }}) alternatively
  }
```

This second approach will make the ecosystem dynamic, allowing you to pass a custom name based on some logic that you will need to add (passing the `name` as a parameter through those functions).

Alternatively, you can look for your state in your `Cabinet` component using `window` object in `window.history.state`.

Comment: Thanks for code, but still `undefined` when i want get data from { location } in anothor component

Comment: Can you try something like: `const handleRedirect = () => {     
   setName("Hello World");    
if(name) navigate('/cabinet/', { state: { name }})
  }`. Basically, setting the name in the same function that the navigate is being triggered.

Comment: I figured out your issue @Bavarius , use the `navigate` like: `navigate("/cabinet/", { state: { yourName: name  },})` Basically, you are missing the key

Comment: I try this `{ state: { name: name }}` but get error when call `location.state.name` 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`

Comment: Can you debug the whole `props` or `location` object to check what's receiving?

Comment: `location` - undefined after debugger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225919/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-bavarius).